# PHP copy() error

Tags: php

I'm getting error while using php function copy()

> Warning: copy() [function.copy]:
>   Couldn't resolve host name in
>
> Warning:
>   copy(http://www.foodtest.ru/images/big_img/sausage_3.jpg)
>   [function.copy]: failed to open
>   stream: operation failed in

what's wrong with that url?

Comment: Can you include the exact code you're using? Is ```allow_url_fopen``` enabled?

Comment: @McHerbie is correct that if your server doesn't have allow_url_fopen enabled then you wont be able to utilize the copy(); method. However a bypass for that is to use the file_get_contents which reads the entire file into a string you can that manipulate.

Comment: I get error only on that file. I do not use allow_url_fopen.  How can I set php, so it pass file he can't donwload and go forward.  Currently, when I get error like that - php stops. Thank you!

Comment: Is it even possible to use copy() with only one argument?  I think it requires ($from, $to). http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing the url withing quotes "".

Comment: @Tuco : Very important to note is that copy() handles url wrappers, but sometimes incorrectly. However, it doesn't work with spaces in filename (as of PHP 5.2.13).
To fix this, you need to replace spaces with %20. Also try changing the file.jpg to some other name  like file1.jpg and make sure it doesnt exist and you have write permissions in that directory.

Comment: @Tuco: Try to get the exact error by running this code:<?php
if(!@copy('http://www.foodtest.ru/images/big_img/sausage_3.jpg','./somefile.zip'))
{
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging in a destination argument and make sure to have the soft ticks around the arguments.

```
copy("http://www.foodtest.ru/images/big_img/sausage_3.jpg", "./file.jpg");
```

Comment: Getting same error. Maybe something wrong in file permession? I get error only on that file

Comment: definetly check the allow_url_fopen in the php.ini as mentioned by @McHerbie and if you cant do that then try the file_get_contents as I mentioned above.

Comment: didn't see you say you get the error only on that file, so this works for other files sourced from different URLs?

Comment: :)  Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.foodtest.ru/images/big_img/sausage_3.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed in

Comment: hah but so it DOES work for other sourced URL's just not this sausage picture?

Comment: worked fine for all other pirctures, but this sausage is very mad :)

Comment: at this point I have to think it is a permission issue on that file :(

Comment: how can I check that and don't let php stop working? 
I need something like that
try {
    copy("http://www.foodtest.ru/images/big_img/sausage_3.jpg", $folder."2.jpg"); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

Answer (score 0):

a little old, but important to pay attention, in case this helps someone who gets here:

**copy command is folder-case sensitive**, so if you try to copy 1.jpg from a folder called "ThumbImages" like that:

```
copy("thumbimages/1.jpg","[destination...]")
```

it will not find the folder.

notice you are using upper or lower case that matches the **folder name**

- I just reached this post while trying to figure out an issue and now that it is solved, I hope it will help others.